# Run tests after build not showing in test explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

According to [this Microsoft article on VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx) there should be a "Run tests after every build" option in the test explorer. There is not. Any idea how to enable it?

[image: vs 2015 test explorer]

I am running VS2015 Update 2, but perhaps there are some additional settings I need to enable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The referred article in your question has a note on the availability on that feature:

> Warning
>
> Running unit tests after every build is supported in Visual
>   Studio Enterprise.

I use Community at home and Professional at work and don't have that feature in either of them.

Comment: BTW, don't be deceived if you're looking at the docs for VS 2017; Enterprise is still required. I created issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1932 to fix the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional and I really want to run tests after build, a feature is only available in Visual Studio Enterprise and currently in Visual Studio 2019 Professional Preview as well. Visual Studio 2019's IntelliSense doesn't do "code completion" well, so I still mainly use Visual Studio 2017.

A work-around to run tests after build in VS 2017 is to run the test from the [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590050/how-to-run-xunit-test-dll-in-commandline-without-building-the-project/44607143#44607143) using [`dotnet vstest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-vstest?tabs=netcore21).

Simply create a batch file to run `dotnet vstest [Your Test Project].dll` and add to `Project Properties > Build Events > Post-build event command line: call $(ProjectDir)YourBatchFile.bat > Run the post-build event: On successful build`.

Below is a sample `Output` after the build:

[image]

Comment: or the batch file can simply be `dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed"`, which can [write the output to the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56791987/4271117).