# How to run xUnit test DLL in Commandline without building the project

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I have a project in .NET Core and have built tests using xUnit. Now I wanted to run the test in deployment process. What I have done so far:

I used this command in commandline:

```
dotnet test [project address]  ...
```

it is working but the problem is that this command get the `.csproj` file and not the `dll`.

I installed and used `xunit.runner.console` but its not working with .NET Core projects.

I used `dotnet xunit` command, this one also not helped while I cannot give it the `dll` it is also using the project folder.

What can I use to run my built test (dont want to build them again), any commandline tools that I can give my test `dll` as an input and it runs the test for me.

Answer (score 41):

You have several options here:

#### 1. Use `vstest` command

```
dotnet vstest Foo.dll
```

to run tests from a `dll`. xUnit tests are supported. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-vstest).

A single `dll` file only is not enough. Run `dotnet vstest` from your `bin` folder, which usually contains:

```
Foo.dll
Foo.deps.json
Foo.runtimeconfig.json
Foo.runtimeconfig.dev.json
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Test.dll
xunit.runner.reporters.netstandard15.dll
xunit.runner.utility.netstandard15.dll
xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
```

This `bin` output is necessary to run the tests.

#### 2. Skip the project build on test run

```
dotnet test --no-build
```

Comment: the vstest is working fine and smoothly. Thanks for your answer it helped a lot.

Comment: I use a task on TFS that execute vstest.console.exe (in the same way as odtnet vstest calls vstest.console.exe). If I call vstest.console.exe mytests.dll it does not work because in the folder containing my test there is not the nunit.framework.dll. These file is in fact referenced in the files .deps.json and .runtimeconfig.dev.json. But these file seems ignored by vstest.console.exe. How to load these files ?

Comment: For people viewing this in recent years vstest has been superseded by dotnet test again: "The dotnet vstest command is superseded by dotnet test, which can now be used to run assemblies"