# not able to print output to console window while running xunit tests

Tags: c#, xunit

```
public class test2InAnotherProject
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public test2InAnotherProject(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }
    int Diff(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a - b);
    }
    int Div(int a, int b)
    {
        return (b / a);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        int a = 2, b = 4;

        output.WriteLine("Test1: Project 2 in old library");
        int c = Diff(a, b);
        Assert.Equal(c, (a - b));
        output.WriteLine("Test1: Asssert done Project 2 in old library");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test3()
    {
        int a = 2, b = 4;

        output.WriteLine("Test2: Project 2 in old library");
        int c = Div(a, b);
        Assert.Equal(c, (float)((b / a)));
        output.WriteLine("Test2: Assert done Project 2 in old library");
    }
}
```

trying to print those lines when test is run through command prompt by using the command

dotnet test --no-build

Tried `Console.Writeline`, after which i tried with `Output.WriteLine`.
Even when i run from Visual Studio am not able to get those lines printed in output window.

Answer (score 14):

Indeed there is no output with `Console.WriteLine`. And the `ITestOutputHelper` output is not shown in the *Output* window. Instead, when you click on the test in the *Test Explorer*, then there is an *Output* link. Click on that link to see the output.

To show the test output on the command line, use `dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed"`.

[image]

Comment: am using the xunit runner class and making another application to run a passed dll tests. dll of test2InAnotherProject is passed to xunit runner implementation which runs the dll in console window.So i would be looking to output to console window when the application is running.

Answer (score 1):

Running `dotnete test` from within powershell console like **package Manager console**  or powershell console ISE, you can get ALL the `Console.WriteLine` output for Xunit project.

In `powershel ISE`, run this script:

```
cls
cd 'path/to/project/test/folder'
dotnet test
```

Also any `Console.WriteLine(..)` in the source code is displayed in the PS console.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that you can use ITestOutputHelper and it should write output.

Please [refer this documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output) for more details.

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public MyTestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var temp = "my class!";
        output.WriteLine("This is output from {0}", temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: according to my code. i have already using ITestOutputHelper still it didn't work.